# Synthesis Golf X: TAK-457

Tags: synthesis-golf

I shall try to revive this!
A full [FAQ post](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3779/everything-you-need-to-know-about-synthesis-golf) has been written on chemistry.meta.SE, explaining the premise of synthesis golf and the 'rules'. Please take a look at this before answering (if you haven't already).

---

**TAK-457** is a drug (more accurately, an injectable prodrug of **TAK-456**) that displays antifungal activity:<sup>[1,2,3]</sup>

[image: Structure of TAK-457]

Some rules, as usual:

- At most one chiral centre may be bought in your starting material(s). [Chiral catalysts, ligands, auxiliaries, etc. do not fall under this rule.]
- Your synthesis must feature a method for construction of either the triazole or tetrazole ring (i.e. do not buy both).
- The counterion doesn't matter.
- Bonus points for synthesis that can be adapted to produce the other three stereoisomers of the drug (preferably via late stage diversification as opposed to, say, using a different enantiomer of starting material). These stereoisomers were of interest.<sup>[4]</sup>

---

*References*

1. Ichikawa, T.; Kitazaki, T.; Matsushita, Y.; Yamada, M.; Hayashi, R.; Yamaguchi, M.; Kiyota, Y.; Okonogi, K.; Itoh, K. Optically Active Antifungal Azoles. XII. Synthesis and Antifungal Activity of the Water-Soluble Prodrugs of 1-[(1​*R*,2​*R*)-2-(2,4-Difluorophenyl)-2-hydroxy-1-methyl-3-(1​*H*-1,2,4-triazol-1-yl)propyl]-3-[4-(1​*H*-1-tetrazolyl)phenyl]-2-imidazolidinone. *Chem. Pharm. Bull.* **2001,** *49* (9), 1102–1109. [DOI: 10.1248/cpb.49.1102](https://doi.org/10.1248/cpb.49.1102).
2. Hayashi, R.; Kitamoto, N.; Iizawa, Y.; Ichikawa, T.; Itoh, K.; Kitazaki, T.; Okonogi, K. Efficacy of TAK-457, a novel intravenous triazole, against invasive pulmonary aspergillosis in neutropenic mice. *Antimicrob. Agents Chemother.* **2002,** *46* (2), 283–287. [DOI: 10.1128/AAC.46.2.283-287.2002](https://doi.org/10.1128/AAC.46.2.283-287.2002).
3. Tsuchimori, N.; Hayashi, R.; Kitamoto, N.; Asai, K.; Kitazaki, T.; Iizawa, Y.; Itoh, K.; Okonogi, K. In Vitro and In Vivo Antifungal Activities of TAK-456, a Novel Oral Triazole with a Broad Antifungal Spectrum. *Antimicrob. Agents Chemother.* **2002,** *46* (5), 1388-1393. [DOI: 10.1128/AAC.46.5.1388-1393.2002](https://doi.org/10.1128/AAC.46.5.1388-1393.2002).
4. Ichikawa, T.; Yamada, M.; Yamaguchi, M.; Kitazaki, T.; Matsushita, Y.; Higashikawa, K.; Itoh, K. Optically Active Antifungal Azoles. XIII. Synthesis of Stereoisomers and Metabolites of 1-[(1​*R*,2​*R*)-2-(2,4-difluorophenyl)-2-hydroxy-1-methyl-3-(1​*H*-1,2,4-triazol-1-yl)propyl]-3-[4-(1​*H*-1-tetrazolyl)phenyl]-2-imidazolidinone (TAK-456). *Chem. Pharm. Bull.* **2001,** *49* (9), 1110–1119. [DOI: 10.1248/cpb.49.1110](https://doi.org/10.1248/cpb.49.1110).

Comment: Those heterocycles are harder than they look... :/

Comment: Adopting this synthesis for late-stage diversification was definitely a challenge, but the Jacobsen epoxidation fit the problem perfectly! I am actually surprised the Jacobsen epoxidation is not taught more in organic chemistry. It is much more versatile than the Sharp Asymmetric Epoxidation.

Comment: @orthocresol♦: I will have to admit, this synthesis was probably the most fun I have had in the last month! Will you be posting more synthesis-golf questions in the future? I enjoy seeing the various approaches to total synthesis people come up with!

Comment: @EliJones thanks, I am glad you liked it. In principle I am not opposed to it. In practice I don't have all that much time (and truthfully there hasn't been that much interest in recent years). You're more than welcome to copy the format.

Answer (score 2):

### Fragment #1 Preparation

[image]

1) An exact preparation of an aryl imidazolidinone (54% Yield)<sup>**1**</sup>
2) A modified preparation of a tetrazole from an aniline derivative (90% yield with pure aniline)<sup>**2**</sup>
3) A modified acetal formation (protocol modifications based on urea) (no reported yield)<sup>**3**</sup>

### Fragment #2 Preparation

[image: Fragment #2]

1) An exact preparation of an alpha-bromophenone (Hell-Volhard-Zelinski Reaction) (97% yield --likely prior to purification)<sup>**4**</sup>
2) Modified coupling of 1,2,4-triazole and alpha-bromophenone (100% yield with chloroacetone -- likely prior to purification)<sup>**5**</sup>
3) Wittig reaction modification (73% yield with phenyl methyl ketone)<sup>**6**</sup>
4) A modified triazolium formation (82% yield with methyl iodide)<sup>**7**</sup>
5) Stereoselective Jacobsen epoxidation (92% yield with 1-phenylcyclohexene)<sup>**8**</sup>

### Final Fragment Coupling

[image: Final Coupling]

1) Deprotonation of the amine with LDA
2) Epoxide ring opening followed by the protonation of the alkoxide and hydrolysis of the acetal to yield the final product

### Stereochemical and General Considerations

The use of the Jacobsen epoxide formation allows for the use of the (*L, L)* Jacobsen catalyst in the final steps of the synthesis to yield the enantiomer of TAK-457. Synthesis of the other stereoisomer would require modification of earlier steps in the reaction.

Longest Linear Sequence: **5 steps**
Total Number of Steps: **9 steps** (I consider the final two steps as one since they are performed without subsequent purification)

Comment on 1,2,4-Triazole Ring: Yes, I did not prepare the triazole ring directly; however, this seems to be the more efficient route.

Comment on Wittig Reaction: This is the step I am probably the most worried about. The steric bulk from the phenyl group may be enough to slightly favor the desired enantiomer; however, this cannot be determined until further experimentation is performed.

### References

1. Stabile, P.; Lamonica, A.; Ribecai, A.; Castoldi, D.; Guercio, G.; Curcuruto, O. Mild, Convenient and Versatile Cu-mediated synthesis of N-Aryl-2-imidazolidinones. *Tetrahedron Lett.* **(2010)** *51* (24). 3232–3235. DOI:10.1016/j.tetlet.2010.04.064
2. Kundu, D.; Majee, A.; Hajra, A. Indium Triflate-Catalyzed One-Pot Synthesis of 1-Substituted-1H-1,2,3,4-Tetrazoles Under Solvent-Free Conditions. *Tetrahedron Lett.* **(2009)** *50* (22). 2668–2670. DOI:10.1016/j.tetlet.2009.03.131
3. Shuai, F.; Wang, X.; Zhang, J. Preparation of Dipyridamole Active Pharmaceutical Ingredient. CNIPA Patent 108069972, Nov 16, 2016
4. Alonso-Alija, Cristina; et al. Preparation of Amino(monocyclic aroyl)pyridinones that Inhibit p38 Map Kinase for use as Antiinflammatory Agents. WIPO Patent 2003076405, Sep. 18, 2003
5. Sun, Y.; Huang, N.-Y.; Ding, M.-W. Efficient Synthesis of 6-(1H-1,2,4-Triazol-1-yl)-thieno[2,3-d]pyrimidin-4(3H)-ones via an Iminophosphorane. *Synth. Commun.* **(2010)** *40* (13). 1985–1991. DOI: 10.1080/00397910903219351
6. Pratsch, G.; Overman, L. E. Synthesis of 2,5-Diaryl-1,5-dienes from Allylic Bromides Using Visible-Light Photoredox Catalysis. *J. Org. Chem.* **(2015)** *80* (22). 11388–11397. DOI:10.1021/acs.joc.5b01962
7. Myles, L.; Gathergood, N.; Connon, S. J. The Catalytic Versatility of Low Toxicity Dialkyltriazolium Salts: in Situ Modification Facilitates Diametrically Opposed Catalysis Modes in One Pot. *Chem. Commun.* **(2013)** *49* (46). 5316. DOI:10.1039/c3cc41588k
8. Brandes, B. D.; Jacobsen, E. N. Highly Enantioselective, Catalytic Epoxidation of Trisubstituted Olefins. *J. Org. Chem.* **(1994)** *59* (16). 4378–4380. DOI:10.1021/jo00095a009

Comment: Wouldn't protecting carbonyl also break tetrazole?

Comment: The protecting step is not necessary for protecting the carbonyl from reacting as much as it is for activating the amide nitrogen. If I tried deprotonating the amide, it would just result in the formation of an alpha-amino alkoxide when I treat it with LDA. It would be difficult to avoid this acetal formation and the tetrazole ring from interfering. I have not necessarily seen any literature claiming catalytic p-TSA would break the tetrazole, but I suppose this is something that would need to be determined experimentally!

Comment: Hmm, prophylactically it probably could be done before forming tetrazole. Let's call it a hunch but this unstable ring might be best made in the end, just to be sure ;)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I thought about forming it before making the tetrazole; however, I think that would render the NH too active. This might then result in a mixture of products when I try to form the tetrazole from aniline. It might be best to form the tetrazole at the end, but my synthesis would be less suitable for late-stage diversification (for multiple stereoisomers).

Comment: If your Wittig isn't selective enough, that's an easy way to access two diastereomers at once. *\*taps forehead\**

Comment: Interesting ... I did not think of it that way! I did not expect the Wittig reagent to be particularly selective and expected to have to separate a bunch of regioisomers with a loss of yield; however, this might not be a total loss -- as you mentioned -- since I could use the 'unwanted' isomer to prepare TAK-457's other diastereomer.

Answer (score -3):

[image]

[image]

Body must be at least 30 characters.

Comment: "Body must be at least 30 characters." Yes, and shoes should be tied. Please clean up your answer, as it stands it's not suitable for prime-time.

Comment: @ToddMinehardt I am sorry the answer is not typed up. I have not had time to type it up and since I left university this year, I do not have access to ChemDraw. Please let me know if any of the reactions are not clear and I will try to elaborate.